# How to detect when SAPI TTS engine is busy

Tags: text-to-speech, sapi

The SAPI engine can only render TTS from one application at a time (I have run a test with two instances of the Windows SDK TTSApplication sample to verify this). I am writing an application in which I need to detect whether the TTS engine is currently speaking (i.e. under control of a separate application, not mine).

Does anyone know please how can I programmatically (in C++) detect the SAPI TTS engine busy/ready state? I have tried using ISpVoice::GetStatus() but that only seems to work for any TTS activity in my own application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is the solution to know whether the speech synthesis system is speaking or not.

`ISpVoice *pVoice;`

`hr = pVoice->GetStatus(& status, NULL);`

`if(status.dwRunningState == SPRS_IS_SPEAKING)`

`std::cout<< "The Speech Synthesis System is speaking."`

`else`

`std::cout<< "The Speech Synthesis System is not speaking."`

Answer (score 0):

For example in SAPI4, IVTxtAttributes::IsSpeaking retrieve such status (if engine is currently playing samples to some audio device).

Anyway IMO general SAPI engine is not limited to one application. I believe that this behaviour is 'your engine' specific.

Answer (score 0):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee431864%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

SPRUNSTATE lists the voice running states.

```
typedef enum SPRUNSTATE
{
    SPRS_DONE,
    SPRS_IS_SPEAKING
} SPRUNSTATE;
```

**Elements:**

**SPRS_DONE**
    The voice has completed processing all queued streams.
**SPRS_IS_SPEAKING**
    The voice instance currently has the audio claimed.